# How to draw a diver in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a diver being trained in a tall water tower in Ti*k*Z?

[image]

All what I have (been able to) do(ne):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,4.5)--(0,0)--(2,0)--(2,4.5);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,4);
\foreach \i in {0.2,0.6,...,3.9}
    \draw[ultra thin,cyan,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (0,\i)--(2,\i);
\foreach \i in {0.4,0.8,...,3.9}
    \draw[ultra thin,cyan,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,dash phase=4pt] (0,\i)--(2,\i);
\draw (-1,0)--(3,0);
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (-1,0) rectangle (3,-.2);
% Do something with the diver at (1,1)
\begin{footnotesize}
\draw[very thin] (1.5,3)--(2.5,3.1) node[right,align=left] {
    sea water\\
    (density 1020 \si{kg.m^{-3}}\\
    or 1.02 \si{g.cm^{-3}})
};
\draw[very thin] (1,1)--(2.5,1.2) node[right] {diver};
\end{footnotesize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I can't draw the diver. I have seen many Ti*k*Z-drawn people on this site, but none of them is a diver.

Moreover, if I could draw the diver, I would also not able to clear the "water" blue dashes behind the diver.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

I'm sorry but I can't provide the image in a better resolution and quality.

Comment: Get a vector drawing of a diver and use Inkscape to export to Tikz. Drawing the diver manually would take hours.

Comment: One can always google clipart diver (see http://www.clipartpanda.com/clipart_images/diver-vector-clip-art-26317902) although most free clipart isn't.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One can draw such things but as Uwe Ziegenhagen says it is a lot of efforts. (Doesn't take hours but certainly more than 10 minutes.) The main problem with such figures is that one is never really done, there is always something that you can tune more.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,4.5)--(0,0)--(2,0)--(2,4.5);
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,4);
\foreach \i in {0.2,0.6,...,3.9}
    {\draw[ultra thin,cyan,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt] (0,\i)--(2,\i);}
\foreach \i in {0.4,0.8,...,3.9}
    {\draw[ultra thin,cyan,dash pattern=on 4pt off 4pt,dash phase=4pt]
    (0,\i)--(2,\i);}
\draw (-1,0)--(3,0);
\fill[pattern=north east lines] (-1,0) rectangle (3,-.2);
% Do something with the diver at (1,1)
\draw[very thin] (1.5,3)--(2.5,3.1) node[right,align=left,font=\footnotesize] {
    sea water\\
    (density 1020 \si{kg.m^{-3}}\\
    or 1.02 \si{g.cm^{-3}})
};
% \draw[red] (0,0) grid[step=0.1] (2,2);
% \draw[red,thick] (0,0) grid[step=1] (2,2);
\begin{scope}[fill=white]
 % back leg
 \filldraw (1.7,0.8) to[out=180,in=-30] (1.3,1)
 to[out=150,in=-20] (1,1.1) -- (1,1.15)  -- (1.1,1.15) 
 to[out=0,in=150] (1.3,1.1) to[out=-30,in=-150] 
 (1.4,1.05) to[out=30,in=130] (1.5,0.95) to[out=-40,in=150] cycle;
 % front leg
 \filldraw (1.6,1.3) to[out=175,in=20] (1.3,1.3) to[out=-160,in=30] (1.2,1.2)
 to[out=-150,in=0] (1,1.1) to[out=180,in=-20] (0.7,1.2)
 to (0.75,1.4) to[out=0,in=150] (1,1.2) to[out=30,in=-120] (1.3,1.4)
 to cycle;
 % belt
 \filldraw (0.7,1.2) to (0.75,1.4) to (0.71,1.42) to (0.66,1.22) to cycle;
 % belly
 \filldraw (0.66,1.22) to[out=180,in=-20] (0.5,1.23) to (0.71,1.42) to cycle;
 % torso
 \filldraw (0.71,1.42) to[out=-100,in=0] (0.55,1.2) to[out=180,in=-30]
 (0.35,1.3) to[out=150,in=-90,looseness=0.4] (0.3,1.4)
 arc(270:30:0.1 and 0.11) to[out=-60,in=180] cycle;
 % hand
 \draw[fill=black] (1.05,1.22) -- (0.95,1.2) arc(-90:90:0.02) -- 
 (1.05,1.24) arc(90:-90:0.01) --
 cycle;
 % arm
 \filldraw (0.95,1.2) to[out=170,in=0] (0.45,1.35) 
 to[out=180,in=170,looseness=1.2]  (0.45,1.45) 
 to[out=-10,in=160] (0.95,1.25) to[out=-20,in=-10,looseness=1.2] cycle;
 % oxygen
 \filldraw (0.8,1.4) to (0.5,1.45) to[out=160,in=160] (0.55,1.55)
 to (0.82,1.5) to cycle;
 % googles
 \draw[thick] (0.38,1.58) -- (0.2,1.5);
 \fill[black] (0.19,1.46) arc(-70:110:0.03) -- cycle;
 % tube
 \draw[double,line cap=round] (0.23,1.45) to[out=-90,in=-70,looseness=1.6] (0.3,1.45) -- 
 (0.26,1.7);
\end{scope}
\draw[very thin] (1.1,1.2)--(2.5,1.4) node[right] {diver};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, you actually drew the diver in tikz there? Amazing. But what I really like to see if someone who can draw the `Mona Lisa` famous painting by Leonardo da Vinci in tikz. But I wonder if a question asking for a `Mona Lisa` drawing using Tikz would be allowed.

Comment: @Nasser This has already been done. Well, almost. See a bit after 4:50 in [this video](https://vimeo.com/305374856). (I recommend watching the video from the start. ;-)

Comment: Ducks are divers too.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity And penguins are even better divers. ;-)

Comment: @Nasser I just use Inkscape to have the *Mona Lisa* in TikZ. 31k lines of code gives me [this](https://i.imgur.com/nauOfYO.png). It is not bad, right?

Comment: @marmot Great!!! Can I give you a suggestion, if is it possible? I think you should give the fins of the diver's right foot a greater curvature.